# DocuSign API Set page orientation

Tags: docusignapi

I see in the web interface that I can rotate document pages individually inside an envelope, but I can’t seem to do it via the API.

The API offers `height` and `width` properties of a `Document`, but they seem to have no effect when I use them via the python client.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. PLEASE check (accept) the best answer to your questions. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to call the `Envelopes::rotateDocumentPage` method using our Python SDK.

For example, should you want to rotate a document page within your envelope, you can do so calling that method on your envelope object, passing in the string "left" or "right" depending on which way you want to rotate the document.

Here a link to the [relevant API reference page.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/rotateDocumentPage)

Comment: Filed DEVDOCS-2395 internally to improve the docs around this method.

Comment: Aptly named. What about setting a document to landscape orientation? This sounds like the same thing, but lets say I'm generating a Document on the fly with a base64 encoded string that needs to be landscape, is that possible also?

Comment: Re: creating a doc in landscape mode. If you're creating a PDF doc you can set its orientation to landscape. (Don't use the API call shown above.) You can probably also use landscape mode with a .docx document but I haven't tested this. Unfortunately, you can NOT supply an HTML original to us and have it use landscape orientation.

Comment: @LarryK It is generating HTML on the fly and attaching it--thank you for confirming it cannot be done, so I can stop trying!

Comment: @RDDBrian -- yeah, I also spent several hours trying the same thing! Then DocuSign engineering confirmed to me that it is not supported. Good news is that generating a PDF on the fly is a lot easier than it used to be.